# Phrase request: The terrible truth

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request, phrases

What can one say to express the cruelness of reality? That's the terrible/cruel/harsh truth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those are fine. You could also use "awfulness of reality" in British English anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ngram is a decent resource for this sort of question, where you have a few candidate possibilities already in mind. For example, search for **[harsh reality](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=harsh%20reality&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Charsh%20reality%3B%2Cc0)** and then click on the **[harsh reality](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22harsh%20reality%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)** link below the graph to consult the attestations and see how a word or phrase is used in context.